# Negative lookbehind Java regex space or nothing

Tags: java, regex

1. Input: `function.abc`

   Output: `newFunction.function.abc`
2. Input: `function.abc`

   Output: `newFunction.function.abc`
3. Input: `pqr.function.abc`

   Output: `pqr.function.abc`

I want to replace `function.` with `newFunction.function.` but only in cases where before `function` only space or nothing is present. If anything else is present, I don't want the replacement to be performed.

I have tried this regular expression:

```
inputValue.replace('(?<!( ))function.','newFunction.function.')
```

But it is not replacing for normal cases either. What could be wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: In your first input there is a `-` before `function`. Should that also be replaced by `newFunction`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this regex that uses a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=\s|^)(function\.)
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/nB2lL9/4)

Comment: I think this is correct, but you can remove the brackets around `function`. It also seems OP wants a literal dot after function, so consider adding `\.` after `function`

Comment: OP has first input as `-function.abc output`

Comment: @anubhava hmmm. could OP mean `\bfunction`?

Comment: @anubhava i guess `-` is for illustrative purpose only.From the title doesnt seem so.

Comment: @Bohemian the postion of `-` remains the same throughout.Guess its a part of `:-` thing

Comment: +1 after recent edits I think this answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputValue.replace("^(\\s*)function.", "$1newFunction.function.")
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mZ9tX1/1)

Comment: Just a minor note: To apply proper syntax highlighting, you can select the code and press Ctrl + K (or indent by 4 spaces).